# Low seg2cat & Stash: Error message when I use it in a conditional

Tags: stash, low-seg2cat

I think I may be getting a parse order problem when I try and use Low's seg2cat variable in a conditional with Stash.

Here's my code:

```
{exp:stash:set name="pg_content_left"} 

    {if segment_2_category_id != ''}

        {exp:stash:set_list name="news_list" parse_tags="yes" parse_depth="2"}
            {exp:channel:entries channel="news" status="open|featured" orderby="date" sort="desc" limit="10" category="{segment_2_category_id}"}
                {stash:item_title}{title}{/stash:item_title}
            {/exp:channel:entries}
        {/exp:stash:set_list}
    {/if}
 {/exp:stash:set}
```

Here's my error message:

```
A PHP Error was encountered
Message: Invalid EE Conditional Variable: {if segment_2_category_id != ''}
```

If I run the IF statement outside of stash:set it fails gracefully. I presume Stash is being parsed before low seg2cat variable is available. Anyone know how I can get around this?

Thanks.

Comment: did you try to setup  *Set all segments* to *Yes* in  seg2cat ext. settings?

Comment: Thank you Max, that did the trick. I wasn't aware of that setting.

Comment: Great, lets add this as answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to setup Low seg2cat extension parameter
**Set all segments** to **Yes**.